# Make a search function by name using Node Express + SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, express, postman

So i wanted to make an API with a search function with SQL queries using node express, this is what my code looked like:

```
app.get('/search/:query', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadId}`)

        search = req.query.search
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM beers WHERE name LIKE '%${search}%' ", (err, rows) => {
            connection.release() // return the connection to pool

            if(!err) {
                res.send(rows)
            } else {
                console.log(err)
            }

        })
    })
})
```

And this is how my postman looked:
[image]

The SQL query is correct but I dont know how to make the search routing in Node

Comment: Possible [sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) alert.

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes i know, but its only for a simple assignment for a course im doing so i dont think it will be dangerous, thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parameter from path variables by this

```js
req.params.query
```

so your code will be like this

```js
app.get('/search/:query', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadId}`)

        search = req.params.query
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM beers WHERE name LIKE '%${search}%' ", (err, rows) => {
            connection.release() // return the connection to pool

            if(!err) {
                res.send(rows)
            } else {
                console.log(err)
            }

        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
app.get('/search', async function(req, res) {
    let page = req.query.page;
    let limit = req.query.limit;
    let search= req.query.q;
    //
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadId}`)

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM beers WHERE name LIKE '%${search}%' ", (err, rows) => {
        connection.release() // return the connection to pool

        if(!err) {
            res.send(rows)
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }

    })
  })
});
```

and call api like this http://localhost:5000/search?q=yoursearchterm, also check for possible sql injection issue.